# How to buffer each worker process's log and flush it when the process completes

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

Here is what I have so far:

```
import logging, logging.handlers
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager


def worker_process(q):

    qh = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(q)
    memoryhandler = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(
        10000,
        logging.CRITICAL,
        target=qh,
        flushOnClose=True
    )
    
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    root.addHandler(memoryhandler)

    for i in range(4):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.log(logging.ERROR, 'Message no. %d', i)
    
    memoryhandler.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Manager().Queue()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        for i in range(4):
            executor.submit(worker_process, q)

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    while True:
        record = q.get()
        logger.handle(record)
```

According to the MemoryHandler docs, I would expect my memoryhandler to buffer the log records and flush them to the queue all at once when `memoryhandler.close()` is called.

However, this is not what is happening here:

```
Message no. 0
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 3
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
```

Why is this the case?

And is there a way to get the following output using the logging library?

```
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are forgetting that this is a multiprocessing application and your processes are writing to the passed queue in parallel and therefore the log records will be in the arbitrary order that you see except for the final 4 records (because you only have 3 processes in the pool and the 4th `submit` call won't actually run until the first 3 `submit` calls terminate and will therefore be running all by itself).

There is also the the additional problem that your main process never terminates because of your `while True:` loop. This could have been resolved by having each task write an additional *sentinel* record to the queue (such as `None`) following the actual log records. Then the main process could loop until it sees 4 of these sentinel records, which, of course, it ignores.

The solution is to use a regular`MemoryHandler` that will not flush the records until `close` is called (and to ensure that this will not happen regardless of what the logging level of the record being written is, we can subclass this class and override the `shouldFlush` method) but then ensure that all the records are flushed under control of a `Lock` so that only one process is flushing at a time:

```python
import logging, logging.handlers
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Lock, cpu_count
import sys

class MyMemoryHandler(logging.handlers.MemoryHandler):
    def shouldFlush(self, record):
        """
        Check only for the buffer full.
        """
        return (len(self.buffer) >= self.capacity)

def init_pool(the_lock):
    global lock
    lock = the_lock

def worker_process():
    memoryhandler = MyMemoryHandler(
        10000,
        logging.CRITICAL,
        target=logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr),
        flushOnClose=True
    )

    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    root.addHandler(memoryhandler)

    for i in range(4):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        # You can even write out CRITICAL level records now without flushing occurring:
        logger.log(logging.CRITICAL, 'Message no. %d', i)

    with lock:
        memoryhandler.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    # Note we are now using a pool size of 4
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(lock,)) as executor:
        for i in range(4):
            executor.submit(worker_process)
```

Prints:

```
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
```

If you want to use a queue as before and not loop indefinitely, then you can use your code modified as follows. Note that I have replaced a *managed queue* with a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance, which is much more performant. But, to ensure that there are no deadlocks, the main process cannot wait to read all the messages from the queue until after the writing processes complete because the writing processes can block writing records to the queue if there is no reader. That is why I have moved the code that reads the records from the queue inside the `with ProcessPoolExecutor(...) as executor:` block. I have also made the queue instance available to the worker function by initializing each process in the pool's global `q` variable (it cannot be passed as an argument or everything will hang when dealing with processing pools).

```python
import logging, logging.handlers
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Queue, Lock, cpu_count
import sys

class MyMemoryHandler(logging.handlers.MemoryHandler):
    def shouldFlush(self, record):
        """
        Check only for the buffer full.
        """
        return (len(self.buffer) >= self.capacity)

def init_pool(the_lock, the_queue):
    global lock, q
    lock = the_lock
    q = the_queue

SENTINEL = None

def worker_process():

    qh = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(q)
    memoryhandler = MyMemoryHandler(
        10000,
        logging.CRITICAL,
        target=qh,
        flushOnClose=True
    )

    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    root.addHandler(memoryhandler)

    for i in range(4):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        # You can even write out CRITICAL level records now without flushing occurring:
        logger.log(logging.CRITICAL, 'Message no. %d', i)

    with lock:
        memoryhandler.close()
        q.put(SENTINEL) # write sentinel


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    q = Queue()
    N_TASKS = 4
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=min(cpu_count(), N_TASKS), initializer=init_pool, initargs=(lock, q)) as executor:
        for i in range(N_TASKS):
            executor.submit(worker_process)

        logger = logging.getLogger()
        seen_sentinels = 0
        while seen_sentinels < N_TASKS:
            record = q.get()
            if record == SENTINEL:
                seen_sentinels += 1
            else:
                logger.handle(record)
```

Prints:

```
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
Message no. 0
Message no. 1
Message no. 2
Message no. 3
```

### `LogHandler` Class

The following `LogHandler` class encapsulates much of the logic that has been scattered in the above code. We do not need to keep a reference to the `LogHandler` instance we create (instantiating it is sufficient) nor do we need to explicitly call `close` on it.

```python
import logging, logging.handlers
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Lock, cpu_count, current_process
import sys

class LogHandler(logging.handlers.MemoryHandler):
    def __init__(self,
                 lock,
                 *,
                 level=logging.DEBUG,
                 stream=sys.stdout,
                 capacity=10000,
                 format=False
                 ):
        self._lock = lock # a "suitable" lock

        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
        if format:
            formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
            stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        super().__init__(capacity,
                       logging.CRITICAL,
                       target=stream_handler,
                       flushOnClose=True
                       )

        root = logging.getLogger()
        root.setLevel(level)
        root.addHandler(self)

    def shouldFlush(self, record):
        """
        Check only for the buffer full.
        """
        return (len(self.buffer) >= self.capacity)

    def flush(self):
        """ serialize """
        with self._lock:
            super().flush()


####################################################

def init_pool(the_lock):
    global lock
    lock = the_lock

def worker_process():
    import time

    # give each process in the pool a chance to run:
    time.sleep(.1)

    LogHandler(lock, format=True) # formatted output

    logger = logging.getLogger(str(current_process().pid))
    for i in range(4):
        time.sleep(.5)
        logger.log(logging.CRITICAL, 'message no. %d', i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=min(cpu_count(), 4), initializer=init_pool, initargs=(lock,)) as executor:
        for i in range(4):
            executor.submit(worker_process)
```

Prints:

```
2021-07-05 07:22:07,925 - 20148 - CRITICAL - message no. 0
2021-07-05 07:22:08,425 - 20148 - CRITICAL - message no. 1
2021-07-05 07:22:08,926 - 20148 - CRITICAL - message no. 2
2021-07-05 07:22:09,426 - 20148 - CRITICAL - message no. 3
2021-07-05 07:22:07,926 - 10864 - CRITICAL - message no. 0
2021-07-05 07:22:08,426 - 10864 - CRITICAL - message no. 1
2021-07-05 07:22:08,927 - 10864 - CRITICAL - message no. 2
2021-07-05 07:22:09,427 - 10864 - CRITICAL - message no. 3
2021-07-05 07:22:07,929 - 8528 - CRITICAL - message no. 0
2021-07-05 07:22:08,429 - 8528 - CRITICAL - message no. 1
2021-07-05 07:22:08,930 - 8528 - CRITICAL - message no. 2
2021-07-05 07:22:09,430 - 8528 - CRITICAL - message no. 3
2021-07-05 07:22:07,930 - 21200 - CRITICAL - message no. 0
2021-07-05 07:22:08,430 - 21200 - CRITICAL - message no. 1
2021-07-05 07:22:08,931 - 21200 - CRITICAL - message no. 2
2021-07-05 07:22:09,431 - 21200 - CRITICAL - message no. 3
```